# Google Analytics Custom Variables won't track

Tags: php, google-analytics

Ok I've been stumped on using custom variables for some time now. I've searched, and followed, the instructions from posts all over the net but, for whatever reason, it simply isn't working.

Here is the code I'm using

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
var pluginUrl = '//www.google-analytics.com/plugins/ga/inpage_linkid.js';
_gaq.push(['_require', 'inpage_linkid', pluginUrl]);
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxx-x']);
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'domain.com']);
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',1,'Enquiry Type','e-Notification']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
</script>
```

One thing worth noting here is the line that sets the custom variable is contained in a PHP IF statement. Essentially I'm only wanting to set this variable after a form has been submitted so that I can capture a value from a select box.

At the end of the day all I want to do is have people fill out a form and capture the value of a select box to pass back to Google Analytics. I don't want the value to be set on each page load so once it _setCustomVar has been run once I destory the session value so that it isn't called again (unless of course the form is completed a 2nd time).

Here is the paramaters constructed to get passed with the GIF (in case it is of any use to help debug this)

```
utmac=UA-xxxxxx-x
utmcc=__utma=247537282.1869531581.1359929325.1365982402.1365984281.5;+__utmz=247537282.1365982402.4.3.utmcsr=domain.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/;
utmcs=UTF-8
utmdt=Request A Call Back
utme=8(Enquiry Type)9(e-Notification)
utmfl=-
utmhid=1514805008
utmhn=www2.domain.com
utmht=1365984805826
utmje=1
utmn=1234674801
utmp=/request-call-back.php?action=sent&oForm=2
utmr=0
utms=7
utmsc=24-bit
utmsr=1680x1050
utmu=qR~
utmul=en-us
utmvp=1680x672
utmwv=5.4.1
```

Through my various tests that I used to bypass the PHP IF statement I have had "some" success. In other words I can on occasion get my test data into the custom variables report but most of the time I can't. There doesn't appear to be a consistent logic as to why a dummy test works and doesn't work.

One last thing, the use of _setDomainName is required as the domain on the account is "domain.com" but the site containing the script is "www2.domain.com". I don't believe this matters to the question but just another thing to bare in mind.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You probably missed the fourth parameter [scope](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables#pageLevel) in the _setCustomVar Method:

```
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',
      1,                   // This custom var is set to slot #1.  Required parameter.
      'Items Removed',     // The name acts as a kind of category for the user activity.  Required parameter.
      'Yes',               // This value of the custom variable.  Required parameter.
      2                    // Sets the scope to session-level.  Optional parameter.
   ]);
```

So, if on a page you set the value and on the same page do not set it at all (not even to a "null"), tghe value might stay at the last level. Same on a per visit and on a per user level.

You should regard the variables as a kind of "property" belonging to a user (lifetime), a session (visit) or a single page view.

From my experience, dealing with this in 90% of the implementations is done wrong.

Besides: leaving out means page level means every hit adds a value (or not).

Remark: I assume, based on your question, this should be session level (2) and not page level (3). And it should only be set if there's a transition in state, what you already implemented in PHP.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've left the scope blank so that it adopts the default scope which I thought would be right for what I'm trying to achieve. This is the first time I've used custom variables and, from what I understood, page level scope is what I'm after. A single user could complete multiple forms and I want to capture the field in the form for each submission. Is this the best way to do that?

Comment: Yepp, usually yes. It also takes some time until the values populate to the report. "latency" can be up to an hour (Visit expiration is 30 mins). So, "click and look" tests may fail, go ahead, get yourself some coffee and ... wait ;-)

Comment: So are you suggesting I try with a scope of "2" instead of null (default 3)? If I'm leaving it as the default them I'm not actually changing my code to test anything new? I'm happy to try with "2" but does that mean I'm just missunderstanding how session-level works?

Comment: It's about the metrics, which are counted. Lets say user A starts a session, makes 5 page views, and after some hours he starts a new session and makes another 10 PV. Depending on level, that will give you 1 User, 2 Sessions and 15 Pageviews. If, for instance, in these pages somewhere you set a value of "Yes" and somewhere a value of "No", these unique values are counted either per pageview (x), per session (2) or per user (1). The information "Yes" has 1 User and "No" has 1 User does not mean that there have been 2 Users (!).